# Transposing a pandas dataframe with correct aggfunction

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as in the code. The output needed is like this. But it seems the aggfunc is not working in the pivot_table. Please refer to the code below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

dataframe:

```
   x   y     z
0  1  Mn  6.78
1  1  na   7.4
2  2  al    32
```

expected output :

```
x  mn     na    al
1  6.78   7.4   0
2   0     0     32
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=[['1','Mn','6.78'],['1','na','7.4'],['2','al','32']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['x','y','z'])
print(df)
print(df.pivot_table(index='x', columns='y', aggfunc=len,values='z'))
```

the output I am getting is (The values of column z are not being filled) :

```
y   Mn   al   na
x               
1  1.0  NaN  1.0
2  NaN  1.0  NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you need `df.pivot` (instead of `df.pivot_table`):

```
df.pivot(index='x', columns='y', values='z').fillna(0)
```

---

```
y    Mn  al   na
x               
1  6.78   0  7.4
2     0  32    0
```